# NavigationView does not switch with page cache enabled/required

Tags: c#, uwp

In the first page I have a navigation view and have enabled page cache on this page. Without pushing any other page on this, I can switch between tabs. But once I navigate to a new page and then pop back the navigation stops working. If I disable the cache all of the state is lost which I dont want. Tried setting it to required too. The pages are not heavy I tested by creating a sample app with just a textblock.

```
<Page 
    ...
    NavigationCacheMode="Required">

    # Navigation View goes here
</Page>
```

In the page pushed on top of the main navigation page, I have below code to dismiss the page.

```
private void OnCloseClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    if (rootFrame.CanGoBack) { rootFrame.GoBack(); }
}
```

Once gone back the navigation simply does not work, what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Could  you share the code  that you used to navigate in the main page? or share a mini sample with github that could reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across the same problem and looks like there's a bug in NavigationView class. Long story short, it is not able to properly recover after Load-Unload-Load cycle (e.g. when it is removed from and added back to view hierarchy - which happens when you navigate from page and back) and stops working.

Update: Checked with NavigationView from WindowsUI SDK. Works like a charm, <strike>only settings item seems to be broken</strike> yet it still has a problem with selecting items with SelectsOnInvoked set to false (aka conditional select).

Comment: I was also using the default WindowsUI SDK, any particular config which you had done ?

Comment: Jus to clarify: I'm talking about this library (which is M$FT-official and meant to be drop-in replacement for built-in controls): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui2/
Which means using `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationView` instead of `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationView`